# Volley error when parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I get an error when I receive the response from a REST server. I found few topics with the same problem but still can't find the solution. This is my code

```
public void clickFunc(View v){
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/Server/file/04";
    final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(), this, this);
    jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
    mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //  mTextView.setText(error.getMessage());
    Log.i("test","error "+error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Object response) {
    // mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response);
    //  mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + "\n\n" + ((JSONObject) response).getString ("name"));
    Log.i("test","ok");
    // Log.i("test",response.toString());
}
```

The error is

```
type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I tried to change the response function in this way

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
```

But I get an error: Method does not override ...

Comment: If that's the error you're getting in your onErrorResponse then you ought to be using a JsonArrayRequest

Comment: yes I get the error on onErrorResponse

Comment: Then you're probably getting a JsonArray as the result of your request. Use a JsonArrayRequest.

Comment: I can't find any example with JsonArrayRequest

Comment: It's pretty much the same, just change it to `JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this)` and don't forget to implement the correct listeners